# Как отличить события клика по элементу от его перетаскивания?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Имеется `<div class="needsToMove">` на странице. Через js добавили метод `.draggable()` и обработчик клика. Как отличать эти события и работать с ними не зависимо друг от друга?

Comment: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/click) [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag)

Comment: Добавьте код примера, неясно в чем проблема

Answer (score 2):

Есть различие между `mousemove`, `mousedown` и `mouseup`.

Вы можете сделать что-то вроде этого:

```js
var flag = 0;
var element = document.getElementById('draggable');
$("#draggable").draggable();
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    flag = 0;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    flag = 1;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if(flag === 0){
        console.log("click");
    }
    else if(flag === 1){
        console.log("drag");
    }
}, false);
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div style = "background-color: red; color: white" id = "draggable">Drag or click me></div>
```

<sup>Для нубов: это выводится в консоль.</sup>
И это работает.